# Remove a particular event listener in EmberJS

Tags: events, ember.js

I would like to only listen the first `didRender` in a EmberJS Component.

```
initialDidRender: Ember.on('didRender', function() {
    // Do some stuff

    this.off('didRender');
}),

allOtherDidRender: Ember.on('didRender', function() {
    // Do some stuff
})
```

Using `this.off` works great for my usecase but if I want to define another `didRender` listener in the future, it will also remove that one.

Is there a way to only disable `initialDidRender` of my example?

I also tried `this.set('initialDidRender', null);` but it throw error on future `didRender` events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `didInsertElement` hook instead of `didRender` hook like this:

```
didInsertElement(){
  // Do some stuff
}
```

Also, you may consider changing the usage of `Ember.on` usage [because they may be deprecated soon](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/issues/174). Take a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f1fc22edc3b45e3cf8dad1230461bf0b) for the usage of `didInsertElement` hook.